# Clojure pattern matching macro with variable arity that goes beyond explicit match cases

Tags: clojure, macros, pattern-matching

I'm in the process of translating some code from Scheme to Clojure.
The Scheme code uses a macro called `pmatch` (https://github.com/webyrd/quines/blob/master/pmatch.scm) to pattern match arguments to output expressions. Specifically, it allows for variable capture as follows:

```
(define eval-expr
  (lambda (expr)
    (pmatch expr
      [(zero? ,e)
       (zero? (eval-expr e)))
...
```

In this use example, some input expression to `eval-expr`, `'(zero? 0)`, should match the the first case. The car of the list matches to `zero?` and the arity of the input matches. As a consequence, 0 is bound to ,e and passed to `(zero? (eval-expr e))`, and this expr is evaluated recursively.
In Haskell, which supports pattern matching natively, the code might translate to something like the following:

```
Prelude> let evalexpr "zero?" e = (e == 0) -- ignoring recursive application
Prelude> evalexpr "zero?" 0
True
```

In Clojure, I first tried to substitute pmatch with core.match (https://github.com/clojure/core.match), which was written by David Nolen and others, but, to my knowledge, this macro seems to

1. only support a single arity of arguments per use
2. only support explicit matching, rather than property based matching (available as guards)

Another option I'm trying is a lesser known macro called `defun` (https://github.com/killme2008/defun), which defines pattern matching functions. Here's an example:

```
(defun count-down
  ([0] (println "Reach zero!"))
  ([n] (println n)
     (recur (dec n))))
```

I'm still exploring defun to see if it gives me the flexibility I need. **Meanwhile, does anyone have suggestions of how to pattern match in Clojure with 1. flexible arity 2. variable capture?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignoring recursive application:

```
(ns test.test
  (:require [clojure.core.match :refer [match]]))


(def v [:x 0])

(def w [:x :y 0])

(defn try-match [x]
  (match x
         [:x e] e
         [:x expr e] [expr e]
         ))

(try-match v)
;; => 0

(try-match w)
;; => [:y 0]


;; Matching on lists (actually, any sequences)

(defn try-match-2 [exp]
  (match exp
         ([op x] :seq) [op x]
         ([op x y] :seq) [op x y]))

(try-match-2 '(+ 3))
;; => [+ 3]

(try-match-2 '(+ 1 2))
;; => [+ 1 2]
```

See https://github.com/clojure/core.match/wiki/Overview for more details.

Additionally, I suggest you have a close look at [Clojure destructuring](http://clojure.org/reference/special_forms#binding-forms). Lots of things can be done with it without resorting to `core.match`, actually your use case is covered.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do you mind providing additional explanation?

Comment: Sure, I don't mind, just could you please let me know what is unclear? I specifically provided an example of what you called "flexible arity" - variable length patterns, and variable bindings (what you called "variable capture".) It seems to directly address your use case, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Do you, by any chance, know how to extend the logic of your example to lists? (e.g., (try-match '(+ 2 2))=> 4)

Comment: See update for matching on lists. You can `eval` the result or do anything else with bound variables.